# How to render inner Css - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, innerhtml

I have an object "Content" contains two properties:

```
Content:{
html:string;
css:string
}
```

and I need to render a div depending on this object, for the html I could do that using:

```
<div [innnerHtml]="Content.html"></div>
```

but I couldn't render the css of the object.
Content example:

```
Content:{
html:"<p>test rendering the object</p> <br> <div class="div1"></div>",
css:"p{color:red} .div1{background-color:black}"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for me was appending the style content programmatically, like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  const css = 'a {color: pink;}';
  const head = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0];
  const style = document.createElement('style');
  style.type = 'text/css';
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
  head.appendChild(style);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) tag directives.

Ex:

```
<div [ngStyle]='style.css' [innnerHtml]="Content.html"></div>
```

Comment: I've tried it , but I got this error : Cannot find a differ supporting object '* { box-sizing: border-box; } body {margin: 0;}*{box-sizing:border-box;}body{margin-top:0px;margin-right:0px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-left:0px;}' @Jitendra